# Inconsistency datetime PostgreSQL default value now()

Tags: postgresql

I have this situation, I have this table named `balance`:

```
id      -> Integer Auto Increment not null
balance -> numeric(19) not null
date    -> datetime default now() not null


id   |   balance    |            date
1          100         2019-09-12 16:15:29.091720
2          99          2019-09-12 16:15:33.404119
3          98          2019-09-12 16:15:33.412087
4          97          2019-09-12 16:15:33.425252
5          96          2019-09-12 16:15:33.442137    
6          95          2019-09-12 16:15:33.513825    -> this time A
7          94          2019-09-12 16:15:33.444407    -> this time B
```

Then I do an insert to the table just 1 column, is balance. Example insert with thread process:

```
INSERT INTO balance(balance) VALUES(100)
```

Date B is lower than A. Where the id increment is 6 then 7, are the process by the id?

Example, id 6 is process first time then insert 7. So 6 must be have time lower than 7?

Any clue why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the transaction that inserted row with id = 7 *started* earlier than the one that inserted id=6 then this is possible. Note that time when the transaction started is important, not the time when the `insert` was executing as part of that transaction.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), `now()` returns the time at the start of the transaction (it's the same as `transaction_timestamp()`, not the "current" time.

If you need that, you should change your default value to `clock_timestamp()`